# Nested awk grab specific string from second match and display

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have file content as

```
0::chkconfig --list autofs::
 autofs                 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

1::grep "^PROMPT=" /etc/sysconfig/init::
 PROMPT=yes

2::rpm -q prelink::
 prelink-0.4.0-2.el5

3::sysctl fs.suid_dumpable::
 fs.suid_dumpable = 0

4::stat /etc/motd::
   File: `/etc/motd'
  Size: 17              Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 10125343    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-04-08 07:54:03.000000000 +0500
Modify: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
Change: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500

5::stat /etc/issue::
   File: `/etc/issue'
  Size: 52              Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 10125494    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-03-30 19:12:13.000000000 +0500
Modify: 2012-02-25 22:01:14.000000000 +0500
Change: 2019-03-30 23:54:57.000000000 +0500
```

I want first match to grab `everything` me between
`:: <everything>\d::`

note:
:: is followed up with \n new line (want to skip first ::)

\d for regex can be 3 places 999 (max).

The second match is to search within the first match
for e.g for `5::`

`Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)`

grab access `0644`

**The second match rule** criteria is not fixed and will change depending upon requirement, but the first match rule is same.

The output of final match be just the matched string and not the whole record or result.

So, far i have tried with 
`cat org_op.2019.04.08-12.49.38 | awk 'f{print;f=0} /^3::/{f=1}'`

which will give me

```
` fs.suid_dumpable = 0`
```

but its not scale to multi-lines matches only gives 1 line below the match

I'm also trying with `awk -F [::,\d""]` but I don't to get \d regex match between bracket.

> FINAL OUTPUT

```
4::stat /etc/motd::
   File: `/etc/motd'
  Size: 17              Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 10125343    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-04-08 07:54:03.000000000 +0500
Modify: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
Change: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
```

> CONDITION # 1
>          Which block to get, is user input for e.g the start tag \d::  where '\d' is user supplied and it will end before start of new block explained above also.
>
> CONDITION # 2
>          See `fd00h/64768d` , but this condition will be changed and be written unique to each block its variable match, I want an awk which I can grow based upon this formatting requirements.

NOTE: from user-supplied i mean it be given as a variable e.g $var

**TESTING**

`cat org_op.2019.04.08-12.49.38 | awk -v id=4 -v RS= -F ':' '($1==id) && $17~/\(([0-9]+)\// { print $17}'`

`(0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid`

Where-infact i want this regex to match `/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\//)` **0644**

Comment: could you add your output for this input? Thank you

Comment: @Allan see update pls

Comment: `\d` is a shorthand for `[[:digit:]]` in PCREs. Very few command line tools will understand that's what you mean when you write `\d`. Just use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` instead for portability to all POSIX tools. Having said that - can you clarify and/or simplify your example? I feel like whatever it is you're trying to do should be trivial but so far I can't understand your explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, which part is more difficult to understand I can improve comprehension.

Comment: `The second match is to search within the first match for e.g for 5::` - There only is 1 block that starts with `5::` and your expected output is the block that starts with `4::`. So what does that mean?

Comment: @EdMorton by block definition is `::\n <everything>\d::` you can see its command name followed immediately by output

Comment: It's all just blank-line separated records to awk. Just tell us what you want to match on in each record and what you want output when the match succeeds.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. You show `FINAL OUTPUT` which is a multi-line record but then there's also suggestions that you might want to output just `0644` from the Access field instead. Which is it? You show the regexp you tried but then say "Where-infact i want this regex to match `/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\//)`" - OK, what's stopping you from just using that regexp instead of the other one?

Comment: I got it working thanks, i used `substr` to get it working. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v id=4 -v str='Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)' -v RS= -F':' '($1==id) && index($0,str)' file
4::stat /etc/motd::
   File: `/etc/motd'
  Size: 17              Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 10125343    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-04-08 07:54:03.000000000 +0500
Modify: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
Change: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
```

Comment: with first `$ awk -v RS= '/^4:/' file` i cannot hardcore to `^4` it is variable, and its value is placed in a variable somewhere.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use a variable. Is that all you're trying to do though - print a record by its ID?

Comment: For second its matching `^5` that another block all-together, i want to search within the first match block which is `^4`

Comment: OK you want to search within the record with ID 4. And then what? Print the record or something else? I updated my answer again.

Comment: Yes, we are getting close `Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)` is variable so for second match can i use `regex` because value of `Access: ` will change but yes field name will remain same

Comment: Yeah, you can use `$0~str` or `match($0,str)` instead of `index($0,str)` to treat `str` as a regexp instead of a string (but then also change the var name from `str` to `re` or similar for clarity) but is it always the `Access` value you're trying to match on or can it be any string?

Comment: I don't have any more time to help you with this right now. Think about what I said and the script I posted and then update your question to make it clearer what it is you're really trying to do so I and/or others can help you with that later.

Comment: no in this case the fields are constants in all file content above it be always `<something constant>:< something variable> is its like key value pair ; the keys be constant so with regex i can easily crawl value of given key (which be a field in case of awk)

Comment: Thanks alot , let me work it on my test machine i will update you with results soon !