# Assign variable to cut -f field

Tags: awk, sh, cat

Using `cut`, I want to know how to use it as:

```
awk -v id=3 -v RS= -F '::'  '($1==id) {print $3}' jenny  | a=1 ;cut -d$'\n' -f$a
```

I want to use it in a loop where `i` is replaced with, e.g., -f 1...3

---

Input

```
0::chkconfig --list autofs::
 autofs                 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

1::grep "^PROMPT=" /etc/sysconfig/init::
 PROMPT=yes

2::rpm -q prelink::
 prelink-0.4.0-2.el5

3::if [ -z "$(grep -l "hard core" /etc/security/limits.conf /etc/security/limits.d/*)" ]; then echo "empty"; else echo -e "$(grep -l "hard core" /etc/security/limits.conf /etc/security/limits.d/*)"; fi::
 /etc/security/limits.conf
/etc/security/limits.d/test

4::sysctl fs.suid_dumpable::
 fs.suid_dumpable = 0

5::stat /etc/motd::
   File: `/etc/motd'
  Size: 17              Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 10125343    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-04-09 07:56:19.000000000 +0500
Modify: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
Change: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
```

Expected Output

```
 /etc/security/limits.conf
    /etc/security/limits.d/test
```

As field 1 and field currently it's all coming in `$3`. I tried separating with newline in awk; it doesn't seem to catch.

Comment: @Allan see update pls

Comment: @Inian see update pls

Comment: I have answered your answer as well! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired output from the given input, try:

```
$ awk '/^$/{f=0} f{print} /3::/{f=1}' file
 /etc/security/limits.conf
/etc/security/limits.d/test
```

To get only one output line as selected with a variable `i`:

```
$ awk -v i=1 '/3::/{n=NR+i} n==NR' file
 /etc/security/limits.conf
$ awk -v i=2 '/3::/{n=NR+i} n==NR' file
/etc/security/limits.d/test
```

The awk variable `i` can, of course, be set to the value of a shell variable `i`:

```
$ i=2
$ awk -v i="$i" '/3::/{n=NR+i} n==NR' file
/etc/security/limits.d/test
```

The stanza can also be selected from a variable:

```
$ i=2
$ k=3
$ awk -v i="$i" -v k="$k" -F:: '$1==k{n=NR+i} n==NR' file
/etc/security/limits.d/test
```

How it works:

- `-v i="$i" -v k="$k"`

  These options set awk variable `i` and `k` to the values of the shell variables `$i` and `$k`, respectively.
- `-F::`

  This sets the field separator to `::`.
- `$1==k {n=NR+i}`

  If the first field of the current line equals the variable `k`, then set variable `n` to the current line number, `NR`, plus `i`.
- `n==NR`

  If the current line number, `NR`, is `n`, then print this line.

Comment: it works as a charm but can regex be also part of value for e.g `/3` also comes from shell variable. Just digit value rest format of regex it follows inline

Comment: @lazereyes No problem.  I just added to the end of the answer code that allows you to do that.

Comment: also please mind explanation of use `n=NR+i` here the default delimator for NR which newline is used? .So  its maintaining two records(NR)

Comment: In awk, each _record_ is divided into _fields_.  `NR` is refers to number of _records_ read.  By default, a _record_ is delimited by a newline.  That can be changed by setting the awk _record separator_ variable, `RS`.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
$ id=3; sed -En "/^$id::/,/^$/{/^[[:blank:]]*\//p}" jenny 
 /etc/security/limits.conf
/etc/security/limits.d/test
```

**Explanations:**

- Your shell will interpret the command and replace `id` by its value.
- `/^$id::/,/^$/{}` the scope `{}` will be executed only between the lines that starts with the value of `id` followed by `::` (`/^$id::/`) until an empty line (`/^$/`)
- `/^[[:blank:]]*\//p` for the lines that start with some POSIX blank character class (e.g. space/tab) followed by `/` print the line. This will print your two paths.

To specify a **line**:

```
$ id=3; line=1; sed -En "/^$id::/,/^$/{/^[[:blank:]]*\//p}" jenny | cut -d$'\n' -f"$line"
 /etc/security/limits.conf
$ id=3; line=2; sed -En "/^$id::/,/^$/{/^[[:blank:]]*\//p}" jenny | cut -d$'\n' -f"$line"
/etc/security/limits.d/test
$ id=3; line=1; sed -En "/^$id::/,/^$/{/^[[:blank:]]*\//p}" jenny | sed -n "${line}p"
 /etc/security/limits.conf
$ id=3; line=2; sed -En "/^$id::/,/^$/{/^[[:blank:]]*\//p}" jenny | sed -n "${line}p"
/etc/security/limits.d/test
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to build onto [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55584195/1745001) rather than coming up with a completely different approach

```
$ awk -v id=3 -v lineNr=1 -v RS= -F '::'  '$1==id{ split($3,lines,/\n/); print lines[lineNr+1] }' file
 /etc/security/limits.conf
$ awk -v id=3 -v lineNr=2 -v RS= -F '::'  '$1==id{ split($3,lines,/\n/); print lines[lineNr+1] }' file
/etc/security/limits.d/test
```